# Is it possible via server side to apply Excel's addin to .csv?

Tags: php, excel, server

i have a .csv file that with the help of Excel and Macros i am applying custom modules to  search, replace or delete old values in the cells.
For example i do replace like this:

```
Sub replace1()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("C:C")
    ary1 = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
    ary2 = Array("1:1@2:6@3:11", "1:2@2:7@3:12", "1:3@2:8@3:13", "1:4@2:9@3:14", "1:5@2:10@3:15")

    For I = 0 To 4
        r.Replace What:=ary1(I), Replacement:=ary2(I)
    Next I
End Sub
```

This Macro among with others i have saved in another excel Addin file (.xlam) so everytime i need to use it on a .csv i add it to the document, i open the vba console and i run it to convert all the cells
I was wondering if it's possible to do it on a server (it is not microsoft server that i have) and if there is such a tool.
My idea is a custom backend with my Excel Addin loaded and i'll import the old .csv file , will convert it with the help of the Addin and then you can save it back without the need of open it locally in Excel as everything is done almost automatically.
Is this possible?

Comment: how do you expect to be able to run VBA on a non-microsoft server?

Comment: I do not know , that is why i am asking. I thought maybe there is an open source Linux solution for such tasks. so no possible?